# Where clause in MySQL using VARBINARY column

Tags: php, mysql, binary

I have a column in MySQL `ip_address` which is `VARBINARY(16)`, and I'm trying to do a where clause conditional on it in `PHP`:

```
       $ip_address = inet_pton($ip_address);

       $SQL = "SELECT location,
                      added
                 FROM ips
                WHERE ip_address = BINARY '" . $ip_address . "'";

       ...
```

However, this is returning `0` rows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: be careful with that sort of thing. the raw binary "garbage" you're inserting into the string can naturally contain SQL metachars (`'` in particular) and break your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.html):

```
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$SQL = "SELECT location, added FROM ips WHERE ip_address = BINARY ?";
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $ip_address);
$stmt->bind_result($location, $added);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch();
```